# Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot system boots to black screen[using ati radeon hd 7340 video card]

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ati, radeon

So this is my third time installing Ubuntu on a Windows 8.1 system and my first time having any issues. Installation seemed to go fine but after the system restarted and tried to boot Ubuntu, it shows the loading screen with dots and then the screen goes black.

After looking up some stuff, I was able to get into the system by editing the Ubuntu GRUB entry but now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to get my video card(I assume the problem is the video card) working correctly. Under my additional drivers in the Software & Updates app, it says that Ubuntu is the X.Org X server open source driver and it won't let me select any of proprietary fglrx drivers

Is there a reason I'm not able to select the other drivers to use?

System: HP Pavilion 23 All-in-One

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue as well. I have an Hp Pavillion g6 windows 8.1 and it has the same error. What I found as 2 potential fixes is :

1. Boot into windows 8.1 and then shift click restart so the Boot from manager shows up. Boot from your different partitions (for some reason my computer has 2 separate hard disk partitions, and try to run normally.
2. Repeat number one, but instead of running normally pick advanced options and select one of the options, it should ask to boot everything in read/write mode but hit no then choose boot normally. 
   Both of these work for me temporarily.

But if anyone knows a final solution that would be good.